# Saving data from android app to remote server

Tags: java, android, server

I am just a beginner in android app development and that's why I have many doubts. I am building one application where the user enters some data in editText. Now I want to save that data in my database. My database is running on my laptop. How would my app connect to the database? Do I need a web server in between? If yes then which web server is used for Android apps? Basically, i want to know the flow of data from app to the database.

Comment: read `what are rest services and how to implement it?` and `how to connect android app to rest services?` and your doubt gets solved.

Comment: [How should I start to implement RESTful web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873864/how-should-i-start-to-implement-restful-web-service)

Comment: "If yes then which web server is used for Android apps?". Well that's _too_ broad to answer on StackOverflow, it depends on the necessary expertise. Some people may have good knowledge in PHP some people in JAVA EE etc. You should try it by yourself. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Study more from Udacity.com, its free.

You may use a jdbc Connector to connect to database.

Connect your jdbc connector over local network ip\servername and database connection string

Comment: connecting to database using `jdbc` is not a good idea. see here [connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233145/connecting-to-mysql-from-android-with-jdbc)

Comment: He is using Android Natively. Thats completely different. Pls study more from udacity.com it will teach you. It's a bunch of free Google sponsored MOOCS. No one can help you if you refuse to learn by your self

Comment: [READ THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST Service when it comes to web Service on Android like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302488/4116560). You can either pass the values as parameters or an Object depending on your requirement. All the best

Answer (score 0):

**Wamp server** is best option to play with server related utilities.You can use it even if you are offline. and it provides various option for data storage. It Mainly uses **MySql** and **PHP** scripts for fast performance.
For More details [Click Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html)

Comment: _"Wamp server is best option to play with server related utilities"_ Why not XAMPP or other? It does the same thing if you're using PHP & MySQL right?

Comment: Wamp Server is easy to configure and If your applications need to deal with native web apps only go for Wamp